# Is this Java TreeSet Possible

Tags: java, equals, comparable, compareto, treeset

Consider that I would like to create a class which manages a TreeSet of custom objects with two keys: A String instance identifier, and a long order identifier. The Long value would be used to determine the order of the elements in the list, while the string would be used to determine if two of these elements are duplicates. To clarify, here is what the methods would look like for the custom object

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if(o == null)
        return false;
    if(!(o instanceof CustomObject))
        return false;

    //Determined by string_id values ONLY. Used in TreeSet implementation
    CustomObject obj = (CustomObject) o;
    return obj.string_id.equals(this.string_id);
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Object another) {
    if(another == null || !(another instanceof CustomObject))
        return -1;

    CustomObject other = (CustomObject) another;
    if(other.long_id > this.long_id)
        return -1;
    else if(other.long_id < this.long_id)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Can my TreeSet function this way? I ask, because while testing this, I've found that my implementation only keeps the latest entry, and discards the rest. I'm looking to find out if this is simply an error with my implementation, or if I'm not properly using the TreeSet class and need to refactor my approach.

Comment: You don't need to check for null before testing `instanceof`.

Comment: Your code breaks the Comparable contract. If two items are equal the should be comparably equivalent as well.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels "It is strongly recommended, but *not* strictly required."

Comment: @shmosel: true, and so I too *strongly recommend* this. Otherwise use a Comparator, not the natural ordering.

Comment: At the very least, `#equals` should take the `long_id` into account. What are you actually attempting to accomplish by doing this? The only way I'd really see these two methods differing being viable is in defining natural order but `(one.compareTo(two) == 0) == (one.equals(two))` should still hold up (equal objects should compare to 0)

Comment: @shmosel: TreeSet API states: *"Note that the ordering maintained by a set (whether or not an explicit comparator is provided) must be consistent with equals if it is to correctly implement the Set interface."* So while Comparable states *"strongly recommended"*, TreeSet states instead ***"must"***.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I'm not at all disagreeing with your point, just nitpicking your statement that it "breaks the Comparable contract".

Comment: @shmosel: Fair enough. It "bends" the Comparable contract but "breaks" the TreeSet contract.

Comment: @Rogue My goal is to order the list by the long id, but to check for duplicates using the string id. If there exists an element with a string id that equals the element being added, the new element should replace the old one, whether or not the long id is equal.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels That was precisely my concern. The documentation didn't make it clear why it works that way, but I figured it was only a standard convention. Based on my needs, do you know of an efficient way I can use the long id to determine the order while checking for duplicates on the string id?

Comment: The issue with this is pretty simple: in this context, "key" means two values are equal if they own the same key and the `TreeSet` is built by comparing entries by their key. Or in other words: you actually propose a system based on two keys: name and id. A `TreeSet` is definitely not the way to go.

Comment: This sounds like you'd prefer having a `TreeMultimap` (or `TreeMap<Long, List<String>>`), but I can't know that because what you're asking is an example of an XY problem. Instead of asking about your actual problem, you're asking about your attempted solution instead.

Comment: @Rogue I think I'm explaining my problem adequately. I need a collection object that will allow me to determine if an element is a duplicate based on its string id so that I can replace it, and to order all of my elements based on their long id. The use case is a set of url objects, each with a url, a title, and a date created. This will be used to track the recent web history of a browser application.

Comment: So ordering browser history, that's a little better. In that case I think your usage here is fine, but I would still add a string comparison if the #compareTo for the longs are equal (to further remove obscure equality).